# How to add a column 'percentage weight' to a MySql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

SELECT country, revenue
FROM mytable

Result is:

```
Usa, 1.000

Canada, 8.000

Japan, 2.000
```

I would like to add percentage 'weight', so :

```
Usa, 1.000, 10%

Canada, 8.000, 80%

Japan, 1.000, 10%
```

Is it possible in MySql maybe with a subquery ?

Thanks

EDIT: i'm very sorry, percentage was wrong !!! Now i've corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`country` varchar(6), `revenue` decimal(4,3))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`country`, `revenue`)
VALUES
    ('Usa', 1.000),
    ('Canada', 8.000),
    ('Japan', 2.000)
;

select
t1.country, t1.revenue, concat(format(if(total.total = 0, 0, (t1.revenue / total.total * 100)), 2), ' %') as percent
from
Table1 t1
, (select sum(revenue) as total from Table1) total;

| COUNTRY | REVENUE | PERCENT |
|---------|---------|---------|
|     Usa |       1 | 10.00 % |
|  Canada |       8 | 80.00 % |
|   Japan |       1 | 10.00 % |
```

- [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3b37/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  SELECT country, revenue
 ,CONCAT(FORMAT(IF(revenue =0,0,(revenue*100.0)/revenue_total_value),2),'%')
  AS `percentage`
  FROM (SELECT SUM(revenue) AS total_value FROM mytable)
```